# Fundmental groups of matrix groups and covering relation between them

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, lie-groups, geometric-topology, classical-groups

I am self studying algebraic topology, the fundamental groups and covering spaces and homologous groups.

I have read the topological properties of classical matrix groups like connectedness, path connectedness and compactness.

Now I want to study the algebraic topological properties of these groups. In particular what are the fundmental groups of patnconnected components of the matrix groups?

Does there exists any relation among the matrix groups via covering spaces?

If anyone provide some referances regarding these questions that will be very much helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, if you have a fibration of spaces - a covering map is an example of one - then there is a long exact sequence of homotopy groups.  Of course, there is also the usual "Galois" theory for covering spaces and fundamental groups.  None of this is specific for matrix groups, though.

Comment: This is way too broad, one can easily write a long survey paper on this matter. I suggest you ask about a particular pair of matrix groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Does there are any book on these? In particular what will be fundmental group of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: $GL(n,R)$ has two connected components, one usually asks for the fundamental groups of connected spaces, in this case, it will be $GL_+(n,R)$ (matrices with positive determinant). This group is homotopy-equivalent to $SL(n,R)$, which, in turn, is homotopy-equivalent to its maximal compact subgroup, $SO(n)$. The latter has either fundamental group $Z_2$ or $Z$, depending on $n>2$ or $n=2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group and references there.